# Scanner.useDelimiter not working as expected

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

The actual answer is supposed to be `stack` and `overflow` in two separate lines for input `stack.overflow`; delimiter used is ".".
Nothing is shown in the output:

```
Scanner p = new Scanner(System.in);

p.useDelimiter(".");

System.out.println("delimiter is "+ p.delimiter());

\\this above line is producing expected output

while(p.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(p.next());
}
```

For input `stack.overflow` and delimiter "." expected output is

```
stack
overflow
```

Comment: You need to do `p.useDelimiter("\\.");`

Comment: but that makes delimiter as "\." right

Comment: `System.in` always `hasNext()` unless you close it. You can always type more.

Comment: Nope. `useDelimiter` accepts a regular expression. Look that up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
p.useDelimiter(".");
```

Delimiter is a regex, and `.` in regex means "every possible character". You are using "every possible character" as delimiter, making Scanner return everything between each pair of characters, which will result in a lot of empty strings.

Escape the dot instead:

```
p.useDelimiter("\\.");
```

Output:

```
delimiter is \.
stack
overflow
```

Comment: i deleted my answer this was correct thanks Stultuske for pointing out my error.